# Excel sorting a lot of data

Tags: excel, formatting, datasheet

I have an excel with a appr. 9000 records (rows). And each row consists of appr. 15 colums. This data needs to be sorted, cleaned up and formatted in an easy to read file.  The problem I have no clue on how to approach this since I'm not really a programmer.

We are talking about a document with questions for education purposes.
Each question has the following colums:

```
-Module
-Procedurestep
-Proceduresubstep
-Lesson
-Questiontype
-QuestionID
-Title
-QuestionText
-DefaultFeedback
-Media
-AnswerID
-AnswerText
-Feedback
-IsCorrect
-AddToDefaultFeedback
```

Find an examle at
http://www.vapa.nl/stackoverflow/excelsheetquestions.png

Looking at the Question ID you can see that the Question repeat itself because of the answers. I would like to format it in an orderly way so teachers can check the questions properly. A question would for instance be formatted like:

http://www.vapa.nl/stackoverflow/excelsheetquestions2.png

The document should be checked for doubles as well. But some of the questions are the same with different alternatives. Also the number of alternatives can vary (mostly 4 or 6).

This way I would like to generate a properly formatted list of questions. 
It's not required that the output should be in excel, Word or another program is fine as well. As long as the teachers can review it easily digitally.

I hope someone can point me in a usefull direction on a short notice. Since I don't want to do it manually :(

Thanks for the help in advance. 
Harold

Comment: For what it's worth, 9000 records is nothing.  When you have over a million and need to split it into multiple sheets, that's when you have a lot.  For now, I'm gonna suggest pivot tables.  Best way to sort your data in a wide variety of ways, and only show what you need to show.

Comment: I'll will take a look at that. Thanks,
I'll report back if this works for me

Comment: Using the built-in Excel Sort &/or Filter capabilities would work. Both are found in the DATA tab of the ribbon in Excel (right near the middle of the items). A little less intimidating for people who aren't big Excel users/data nerds